# Could not create shared memory segment. Failed system call was shmget. PostgreSQL MacOS Mojave. Symlinked postgres data directory

Tags: postgresql

This is a common error message and there are many general answers that have not worked for me.

I think I have isolated this particular problem to the PostgreSQL data directory being symlinked to an external hard drive.

```
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: No space left on device
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=56, 03600).
HINT:  This error does *not* mean that you have run out of disk space.  It occurs either if all available shared memory IDs have been taken, in which case you need to raise the SHMMNI parameter in your kernel, or because the system's overall limit for shared memory has been reached.
```

```
$ sysctl -a | grep sysv
kern.sysv.shmmax: 412316860416
kern.sysv.shmmin: 8
kern.sysv.shmmni: 64
kern.sysv.shmseg: 128
kern.sysv.shmall: 100663296
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sysctl.conf
kern.sysv.shmmax=412316860416
kern.sysv.shmmin=8
kern.sysv.shmmni=64
kern.sysv.shmseg=128
kern.sysv.shmall=100663296
```

PostgreSQL version 9.4.15. From my PostgreSQL config

`shared_buffers = 128MB`

Don't know what other settings would be relevant.

Other environment details:

The external hard drive with the data directory is at only 50% capacity. My RAM usage when this happens is ~60% capacity.

I have not been able to determine an exact set of steps that reproduces the bug. I have an external hard drive with a PostgreSQL data directory and a local folder with another data directory. In my project, I'll symlink to one or the other depending on which copy of data I want to use. As far as I have noticed, the problem only appears when I've been working off the symlinked hard drive and when I unplug it without stopping the server and then plug it back in. But it doesn't happen every time when I perform those steps.

I don't expect anyone to be able to point to the specific problem given the above description.

But how can I get more useful information next time I'm in a bugged state? Are there any system commands that would help identify the exact problem?

> ...It occurs either if all available shared memory IDs have been taken, in which case you need to raise the SHMMNI parameter in your kernel, or because the system's overall limit for shared memory has been reached.

How can I check if `if all available shared memory IDs have been taken` or if `the system's overall limit for shared memory has been reached` and what do I do with the answer?